# Android override YoutubeBaseActivity API

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I am using the YoutubeAndroidAPI.jar library in order to play songs from youtube. It is working great. Unfortunately when the activity enters onPause the music stops playing.

Is there a way to find the code in maven or somewhere else? Using JD-GUI the code for the class is obfuscated.

If I could copy the class I could use it as is without calling the player.stop() or equivalent method which I assume is being called.

Answer (score 0):

The only code you can find is inside the `YoutubeAndroidAPI.jar` file, since this SDK is not open-source.

For what I have seen (using JD-GUI), most of the methods are marked as `final` and cannot be overridden. **So you're going to have an hard time trying to get around this limitation.**

As a side note, keep in mind that the SDK requires the YouTube app to be installed, hence acting like some sort of a "remote view" on the player app.

Comment: That is exactly what I said. I asked how exactly can I get my hands on the unobfuscated code.

Comment: You asked whether it was possible to find the code somewhere else, and the answer I gave you is no, you cannot, because the SDK is not open-source. You also expressed your will to try and get around this limitation: I replied that this probably will not work, also adding a series of reasons why. What were you expecting, exactly?